# How To Create Splash Screen in FireFox Mobile App

Tags: firefox, jquery-mobile, firefox-os

I want to create the splash screen for my firefox os app how can i do so. can any one know how to do so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two pages and call the transition after some time, example

```
    <div data-role="page" id="splash"> 
        <div data-role="content">  
            <img src="images/splash.png" alt="startup image" style="width: 100%; height: 100%" />
        </div>
    </div>


    <div data-role="page" id="home"> 
        <div data-role="header" data-backbtn="false">
            <h1>New page!!</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
   New content!<br/>
   Test!!
        </div>
    </div>
```

Then use this script for changing pages

```
  $('#splash').on('pageshow', function(){
       var hideSplash = function() {
           $.mobile.changePage($("#home"));
       };
      setTimeout(hideSplash, 2000);
  });
```